# Object to display video in IE needs a thumbnail

Tags: html, internet-explorer, object, video, thumbnails

I am using the object tag to display a video in IE. But I can't seem to create a thumbnail image.

```
<object width="150" height="104" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" class="vjs-flash-fallback" style="margin-top:-23px; margin-left:-12px;">
      <param value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" name="movie">
      <param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">
      <param value="config={&quot;clip&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;english_short.mp4&quot;,&quot;autoPlay&quot;:false,&quot;autoBuffering&quot;:true}}" name="flashvars">
     <!-- Image Fallback. Typically the same as the poster image. -->
    <img src="screen.png" width="150" height="104" alt="Poster Image"
      title="No video playback capabilities." />
      <img class="vjs-poster" style="width: 640px; height: 264px; display: block;" src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"/>
    </object>
```

Comment: how can I make a thumnail image that shows up when play has not yet been pressed. Right now its just a black screen

Answer (score 1):

There's no feature that I know of to do this.

What is usually done instead is a static image is created in an image editor and placed where the image should go. When the user clicks the play button, javascript replaces the image with the video as a seamless transition.